# GET from 2 different MongoDB collections using MongoJS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs, mongojs

I am using MongoJS to fetch data from mongo db in the following way: app.js:

```
var db = mongojs('db', ['events']);
```

And then:

```
   app.get('/', function(req, res){
    db.events.find(function(err,docs){
        res.render('index', {
        title: 'Events',
        events: docs
    });
    })  
});
```

This method works, I then fetch it using ejs as the view engine the following way: index.ejs:

```
<% events.forEach(function(event){ %>

<a><%= event.event_name %></a></br>
<a><%= event.event_description %></a> 

<% }) %>
```

This all works, however, **How could I grab data from a different collection in the same ejs page?** I've been trying to do it the following way: app.js: edited into

```
var db = mongojs('db', ['events', 'groups']);
```

And then:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
        db.events.find(function(err,docs){
            res.render('index', {
            title: 'Events',
            events: docs
        });
        })  
    });


       app.get('/', function(req, res){
        db.groups.find(function(err,docs){
            res.render('index', {
            title: 'Groups',
            groups: docs
        });
        })  
    });
```

Followed by the EJS:

```
<% groups.forEach(function(group){ %>

            <p><a><%= group.group_name %></a></br>
            <a><%= group.editor %></a></p>
            <a><%= group.members %></a></p>

 <% }) %>
```

The error that I'm getting is that 'groups' is not defined, however if I flip them like this inn app.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
            db.groups.find(function(err,docs){
                res.render('index', {
                title: 'Groups',
                groups: docs
            });
            })  
        });

app.get('/', function(req, res){
            db.events.find(function(err,docs){
                res.render('index', {
                title: 'Events',
                events: docs
            });
            })  
        });
```

Then it says events is not defined. How do I declare them both in one without one overwritting the other? If you can help with this, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one root `app.get('/'...` call. Try combining your routes like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    db.groups.find(function(groupsErr, groupDocs){

        // now get events
        db.events.find(function(eventsErr, eventDocs){
            res.render('index', {
                title: 'Events',
                events: eventDocs,
                groups: groupDocs
            });
        });
    });
});
```

You can also handle this in a slightly prettier fashion (less nested) using `promises`.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    let groupsPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        db.groups.find((err, docs) => {
            if (!err) res(docs);
            else rej(err);
        });
    });

    let eventsPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        db.events.find((err, docs) => {
            if (!err) res(docs);
            else rej(err);
        });
    });

    Promise.all([groupsPromise, eventsPromise])
    .then(docArr => {
        let groupDocs = docArr[0];
        let eventDocs = docArr[1];

        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Events',
            groups: groupDocs,
            events: eventDocs
        });
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for both methods! However I prefer the shorter uglier one for easily understanding what's going on!

Comment: Haha ya I don't blame you. If your callback functions get crazy complex, and nested, I'd recommend looking into promises.

Answer (score 0):

After the first handler gets executed, the second one does not, so the simplest way is to chain your queries as:

```
let events;
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
db.events.find(function(err, docs) {
  events = docs;
  db.groups.find(function(err, docs) {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Items',
      groups: docs,
      events: events
    });
  })
});
})
```

The code above, couls be improved with the use of promises or async/await. I recommend you search about **asynchronous functions** for better programming in Javascript

Comment: I'm glad to know  @MrG .. If the answer was helpful/ solved the issue, It is good and encouraging practise to upvote or set it as the correct answer, so that others know it worked for your case

Comment: I did so, but as I have less than 15 reputation it does not register